# How to covert IplImage to Texture2d in Unity

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm using opencvsharp in Unity.

And I want to convert iplImage to Texture2D. I want to do it like this:

```
Texture2D alphaTexture = new Texture2D(1024, 768, TextureFormat.Alpha8, false);
alphaTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
alphaTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

IplImage originIplImageAAA = Cv.CreateImage(new CvSize(1024, 768), BitDepth.U8, 1);
Cv.Zero(originIplImageAAA);

int imgSize = originIplImageAAA.ImageSize;
IntPtr aa;
int step;
CvSize rawSize;

originIplImageAAA.GetRawData(out aa, out step, out rawSize);

byte[] imageData = new byte[imgSize];

Marshal.Copy(aa, imageData, 0, imgSize);
alphaTexture.LoadImage(imageData);
```

But it does not work. How do I convert it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is saving the image to local and load it back to the Texture2d object using the WWW class. It works fine always and by assuming it is a PC, it is not going to be a performance drop.

There is a hard way around. I would post the sample if you still need it.

PS: A texture loaded from local with WWW will be executed like a normal function call, so even www is not needed. This applies for standalone only.

Comment: I tried what you said and.And i find it is a bit slow. Could you tell me the hard way solution